# Database info missing on drush status

Tags: drupal, drush

Why would this happen? when I run drush status it completely skips my database:

```
drush status

Drupal version         :  7.38                                                                      
Site URI               :  http://default                                                            
PHP executable         :  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.23/bin/php                              
PHP configuration      :  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.23/conf/php.ini                         
PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                                                    
Drush script           :  /usr/local/Cellar/drush/HEAD/libexec/drush.php                            
Drush version          :  8.0-dev                                                                   
Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                                                      
Drush configuration    :                                                                            
Drush alias files      :  /Users/Ambi/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php                                    
                   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/UCLALIB/www/sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php 
Drupal root            :  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/UCLALIB/www                                     
Site path              :  sites/default
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Drush will work if I append @bs after drush i.e. 'drush @bs status' works because aliases.drushrc.php has this line:

```
// Your local development server.
$aliases['bs'] = array(
...
```

(drush status -- does not work):